# What should be the semantics of a reference to const string in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

There are several ways to pass textual information into a function in C++: that could be a c-string/std::string, by value/by reference, lvalue/rvalue, const/mutable. C++17 adds a new class into the standard library: `std::string_view`. The semantics of the string_view is to provide read-only textual information without ownership. So if you need just to read a string you may use:

```cpp
void read(const char*);        // if you need that in a c-style function or you don't care of the size
void read(const std::string&); // if you read the string without modification in C++98 - C++14
void read(std::string_view);   // if you read the string without modification in C++17
```

My question is if there any case when `void read(const std::string&)` should be preferred to `void read(std::string_view)` in C++17. Assume that backward compatibility is not needed.

Comment: @Fureeish I don't think a 2012 question can be a duplicate of one about C++17 features.

Comment: @Fureeish, the question you are pointing to is completely different. It has nothing to do with `std::string_view`. One answer on that question touches the topic but has no comprehensive answer on my question.

Comment: Taking `const std::string&` / `const char*` might be preferred, for example, when you pass that string to some C api. This is the main reason (afaik) why `std::fstream` constructor doesn't have an overload taking `std::string_view`.

Comment: @Evg, if you are satisfied with `const char*`, you can easily get it from `std::string_view`. That is the opposite to my question: it is not `std::ostream` who needs the `const std::string&`, but that is the client who may already have an `const std::string` and wants to use it with the `std::ostream`.

Comment: You can't get a C string from `string_view` because it won't be null-terminated.

Comment: No, you can't. `std::string_view` can be not null-terminated and then there is no way to put a null terminator there without making a copy.

Comment: @interjay, Eng, ok, agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you *need* null-termination? If so, you have to use one of these:

```
// by convention: null-terminated
void read(const char*);

// type invariant: null-terminated
void read(std::string const&);
```

Because `std::string_view` is just any contiguous range of `char const`, there is no guarantee that it is null-terminated, and it's undefined behavior to try to peek past the last character.

If you do *not* need null-termination, but need to take ownership of data, do this:

```
void read(std::string );
```

If you need neither null-termination nor ownership nor modification of data, then yeah your best bet is:

```
void read(std::string_view );
```

Comment: Ok, null-termination is the aspect I didn't regard asking the question. That makes sense if you need a `const char*` to call a low-level function but need a richer interface to make some checks before that (otherwise you should prefer `const char*` as the parameter type). Are there any other valid reasons to prefer `std::string const&`?